# How to add Normal viewcontroller after navigation controller in windows based application?

Tags: ios4, uinavigationcontroller

In my windows based applicaton, after login screen and registration page I added navigation controller for next two views. After pressing  button present on second navigation window,again i want normal view controller and not navigation. But Its giving me navigation window with back button which takes me to second navigation window.
Can anyone plz tell me the solution??

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple choices: you can truly eliminate the Navigation Controller entirely and replace it with another UIViewController (more complicated), or you can just push a new UIViewController that will not have a navigation bar/back button, and use that as the effective "root" view controller of your application from there on out.   Without the navigation bar, your view controller will look like a "normal" view controller.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
    ...
}
```